# Function for all prototypes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, video.js

I'm working on a video player with video.js.
On this side I've got elements (volume, fullscreen, play, pause...) which are **prototypes**. On the other side I've got my functions **parse()** which is going to be use by all of the canvas prototypes (they come from different elements).

parse Function :

```
vjs.parseHex = function(c) {
    if(c.charAt(0) == "#") {
        return c.substring(1,7);
    } else if(c.substr(0,2) == "0x") {
        return c.substring(2,8);
    } else {
        return c;
    }
},

vjs.parseRed = function(c) {
    return parseInt((this.parseHex(c)).substring(0,2),16);
},

vjs.parseGreen = function(c) {
    return parseInt((this.parseHex(c)).substring(2,4),16);
},

vjs.parseBlue = function(c) {
    return parseInt((this.parseHex(c)).substring(4,6),16);
}
```

An exemple of my canvas prototype :

```
js.VolumeBar.prototype.drawSound = function(){
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I want that my parse functions are accessible by all of the different prototypes. Is that possible ? If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you for helping me,
Léa.

Comment: `js.VolumeBar.prototype.parseHex = vjs.parseHex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that vjs is a sort of Util namespace that contains a few functions that should be used in different places. As long as that is public it can be used anywhere:

```
vjs = {};
vjs.parseHex = function(c) { /*...*/ }
vjs.parseRed = function(c) { /*...*/ }


js.VolumeBar.prototype.drawSound = function(){
  vjs.parseRed(stuff);
}
```

Keep in mind that if you pass `vjs.parseRed` as a callback, it will be called with a different object as `this` than what you expect. You could rewrite it to either

- replace `this` with `vjs`:

  `vjs.parseRed = function(c) {
      return parseInt((vjs.parseHex(c)).substring(0,2),16);
  }`
- bind the functions when you pass them as parameters:

  `doAsync(vjs.parseRed.bind(vjs));`
- or just bind them when you define them:

  `vjs.parseRed = function(c) { /*...*/ }.bind(vjs);`

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me. I didn't know that I can bind functions, so I'm really grateful :).
Now, I've got another problem concerning my charAt (Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined). I'll try to solve it.